# Android showAlertDialog function, R.drawable.success and fail

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-drawable

I've got a showAlertDialog class from online samplecode and one of the lines is giving me an issue:

```
  alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);
```

its telling me "success cannot be resolved or is not a field" and "fail cannot be resolved or is not a field". Is there somewhere I should have/put these icons? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an easy fix those icons should be in your `res/drawable` folder. If you haven't made these icons ever, you need to do so. Through photoshop/an image editor/from the internet/wherever. But they do **need** to exist.

Their filenames (assuming a png extension) should be:

```
success.png

fail.png
```

However, this will look bad on varying devices since `drawable` is the density independent folder for your drawables.

Instead, make different sizes for ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi and put your icons there.

Your folder structure should be:

```
res/
   drawable-ldpi/
   drawable-mdpi/
   drawable-hdpi/
   drawable-xhdpi/
```

For more info, read up on [Suppporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [Designing For Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html).

Comment: Yeah I have several drawable-* folders in res but they are all either empty or just have an ic_launcher icon. So I should download the images success.png and fail.png

Comment: @alex9311 yes, you will have to make those icons. Make sure the filename is `success.png` and `fail.png` respectively. Usually stick with png images.

Comment: would just changing it to   alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.ic_launcher : R.drawable.ic_launcher); be a temporary fix?

Comment: @alex9311 Yes, those images exist and are valid.